# how to print 5 different variables in php using loop (without using ARRAY)

Tags: php

I want to print this variables using loop(any type of loop) without using array. Or you can suggest me this answer in any type of programming language.

PHP CODE:-

```
<?php
  $answer_1 = 4;
  $answer_2 = 8;
  $answer_3 = 5;
  $answer_4 = 3;
  $answer_5 = 2;
  ?>
```

Comment: [Array.](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php)

Comment: I don't want to use array.

Comment: sorry for asking a stupid question, but WHY wouldn't you want to use an array? this smells...

Comment: @Sonu Kumar Pandit, why not???

Comment: _“I don't want to use array”_ - yes you do. “Numbered” variable names is something you should stay away from, that’s what we have arrays _for_. If you have data with multiple records/items/whatever of the same structure and meaning, then that data belongs into an array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PHP supports [variable variables](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php) feature (but consider using an array):

```
<?php
$answer_1 = 4;
$answer_2 = 8;
$answer_3 = 5;
$answer_4 = 3;
$answer_5 = 2;

for($i = 1; $i <= 5; $i++) {    
    $variable = ${'answer_'.$i};
    echo '$answer_'.$i.': '.$variable;
    echo '<br>';
}   
?>
```